# Does tweepy's search filter allow searching for a substring in a string?

Tags: python, tweepy

If I am currently searching `tweepy.Cursor(api.search, [obama])`, will this return tweets that only contain the hashtag `#obama` but not `obama`?

What I am trying to ask is whether or not `api.search` will return tweets that have strings that contain the search term(s) as a substring?

example of what I want: 
`tweepy.Cursor(api.search, [obama])` returns a tweet such as:

**greatest president ever! #obama**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use #obama if you want to fetch tweets starting with #

```
tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, ["#obama"]).items(4)
    for tweet in tweets:
        print(tweet.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
RT @afbranco: A.F. Branco Cartoon - Yes We Cage  #KidsInCages #Obama #Obamacages #BorderCrisis
BEHIND THE COMFORT WOMEN CONTROVERSY: HOW LIES BECAME TRUTH / N.Tsutomu #Obama #Clinton #Bush #GOP
RT @christinagala17: @davidaxelrod Can't defend the indefensible.  There was NOT a #MüellerInvestigation. He hired ONE lawyer, you know, yo…
RT @LongDefense: These appear to be the last minute changes made by #Obama Admin days before #Trump took office loosening dissemination of…
```

Comment: i see, so theres no way to search for substrings?

Comment: That's not at all a valid conclusion.